# Как сохранить в память компьютера данные c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, память

Привет. Есть консольное приложение, где, допустим, вводятся имена людей и потом сохраняются в векторе. 
`std::vector<std::string> people;std::string name;std::cin >> name;people.push_back(name);`
Вопрос в том, как сохранить этот заполненный вектор в памяти компьютера, чтобы при следующем открытии этого приложения, не пришлось заново заполнять его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняйте имена людей в файл на жестком диске.

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int peopleNumber;
    string name;
    ofstream f; //описывает поток для записи данных в файл

    //открываем файл в режиме записи,
    //режим ios::out устанавливается по умолчанию
    f.open("D:\\names.txt", ios::out);

    //вводим количество людей
    cout<<"People number="; cin>>peopleNumber;

    //цикл для ввода имён и записи их в файл
    for (int i=0; i<peopleNumber; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Name=";
        cin>>name;     //считывает из консоли введенное имя
        f<<name<<"\t"; //запись в файл
    }
    f.close(); //закрытие потока
    return 0;
}
```

Только в вашем случае вам нужно пройтись циклом по вектору, считывать имена и записывать в файл

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить проверку: открыт ли файл? Закрытие потока, кстати, не обязательно. Он будет закрыт в деструкторе.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сохранить содержимое вектора в файл и добавить в опции запуска программы ключ для задания источника данных: файл или ввод в консоли.

Answer (score 0):

В решении данной задачи вам поможет помочь сериализация\десериализация данных.